# How to change swipe behaviour in Gmail on iPhone Safari from Archive to Delete?

Tags: gmail, mobile

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the swipe behaviour in Gmail on iPhone Safari from Archive to Delete?

I know this can be done in the native iPhone mail app on iOS 4, but I'm specifically asking about the Mobile Safari version. When I'm on my work WiFi network we can't get directly to the Gmail IMAP servers so I leave a Safari session open and would like to change the swipe behaviour to be consistent with the Native Mail app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it's possible with the web version.

It's possible on the native Mail app because it's simply changing the folder where a swiped messages goes; it works with all hosts because Mail just says "move this message to folder X".

However, the Gmail online app isn't an IMAP client that says "move this message", but instead is Gmail itself. It would be like trying to change the function of the "Archive" button on the computer version of Gmail to do a delete instead: changing the functionality instead of the destination.

Comment: Archive isn't a folder per se is it? It isn't exposed as one in the web version and isn't in the Native Mail app. I think it might be possible to do this in the web version but it isn't configured to do this. A setting to choose the behaviour is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Archive isn't a folder, it is a lack of having the inbox label.  Archiving is really just removing the inbox label.

Comment: archived with no labels is the same as only having the internal label All Mail